# Trying to add spring-boot-starter-data-jpa with gradle

Tags: eclipse, gradle

I'm trying to add this dependency to my project using gradle:

`implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:3.1.3'`

So I clean and cleanEclipse after adding it to my build.gradle. However, no matter the verion I choose from https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa, there is no .jar, only a few files including a manifest. Is this normal? What should I use as dependency for Data JPA?

Comment: springboot starters are not standard jar module dependencies , they are dependencies descriptors that will bring required transitive dependencies to your project. in case of spring-data-jpa, il will be hibernate-core and other, . see https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/spring-boot-starters/ and  https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-starters

Answer (score 0):

It does not seem normal.Try this:

```
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
```